# Comment dire "it's all over the place" en français ?

Tags: traduction

En anglais, on dit souvent "it's all over the place" pour signifier qu'un discours, un essai, ou un film parle trop de sujets et n'a pas de thème unifié. Je suis curieux de savoir comment le traduire en français. Merci d'avance !

Comment: Ça part dans tous les sens

Comment: Pas de fil conducteur, pas d'unité

Comment: Hi folks, if you have an answer to give, please don't use comments but rather the "answer" feature. This is what this site is about, thanks! :)

Comment: @Reyedy Je n'ai pas voulu écrire de réponse, parce que le *ça part dans tous les sens* me semble être la meilleure solution

Answer (score 2):

"**Ça n'a ni queue ni tête, c'est sans queue ni tête**" ([internaute](http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/19452/sans-queue-ni-tete/)); un thème qui n'a ni queue ni tête

Autre terme: **décousu**; un thème décousu